# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItemFactory

Tags: java, spring-mvc, maven

I am trying a simple example of file upload in spring MVC using maven and I follwed this [tutorial](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/spring/spring3/web/spring-3-mvc-fileupload-example.html).

But I am getting this error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItemFactory
```

I also included the dependencies in pom.xml

```
<!-- Apache Commons Upload --> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

also in dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<!-- Configure the multipart resolver -->
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000"/>
</bean>
```

Where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 148):

You need to add [`commons-fileupload`](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/)

add this to your POM

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.1</version> <!-- makesure correct version here -->
</dependency>
```

Comment: I haven't read the rose india's tutorial, but it might be using it somewhere. do one thing just remove it and check for exception or compilation error. and you are always welcome (also to mark answer accepted :))

Comment: version 1.2.2 available: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload

Comment: I had a similar tomcat 7 starting issue, by ready the Eclipse console logs, I found out that I was missing some jars needed by Primefaces fileupload. After adding those jars i.e. commons-io and commons-fileupload, I got rid of the tomcat starting issue... :)

Comment: Note that these dependencies have to go on the highest artefact classloader (EE types, this is your EAR, not your WAR).

Comment: Better narrow down the scope to runtime. `<scope>runtime</scope>`

Answer (score 2):

For the **security** use version 1.5 :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
   <version>1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Check : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload