# ClassNotFoundEcception when running jar through Terminal (or command prompt)

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies, classnotfoundexception

So I know there are tons of questions like this one, and I have been through all of them, but I can't seem to find one like mine.

Basically, I have a java project with a lot of Maven Dependencies. The project compiles and runs just fine when I run it with IntelliJ, but now I am trying to run it through the terminal (or command prompt). In order to do that, I ran mvn package so I can get a jar file and when I run `java -jar server.jar`, I get the classic ClassNotFoundEcception exception. In my case, it says that it is:

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory`

and when I suppress it by (temporarily) commenting out the part of the code that uses this class, I end up with the same error for another class. At this point, I know that I need to have some sort of folder (correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe it is called CLASSPATH) which contains the .jar of each dependency. Can anyone explain to me the situation in a clear way and how am I supposed to organize the .jar file of each dependency (if that is even what I have to do to fix my error).

Comment: this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166898/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-commons-fileupload-fileitemfactory)  should be usefull

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItemFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166898/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-commons-fileupload-fileitemfactory)

Comment: Not really, I tried but it still doesn't work. What I want to know is maybe where the dependencies are located when running the program in IntelliJ. This could help me understand where I need to put them when running the file from the Terminal. @Morteza Jalambadani

Comment: extract your jar file and sure to contains this files.

Comment: contains which file ?

Comment: which file is not found? your question is about org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItemFactory

Comment: @MortezaJalambadani if you read the question correctly, you would have known that I said that this issue is to all my dependencies (not only the FileItemFactory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory` and most likely other dependencies are not in the classpath. Intellij includes dependencies in the classpath automatically, and this is the reason it works.

To run the program from CMD with all your depedecies included define the following plugin in `pom.xml`:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    
        <configuration>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
    
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>make-assembly</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

and run:

```
mvn clean package
java -jar server-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Comment: Okay I see what this means and that is exactly what I was looking for!! Now when I did that, it created two .jar files. The first one being my server.jar. The second one contains all the dependencies (when I extract it, I can see them all). When I run java -jar server.jar, it still doesn't work. Is there a way I should specify where the dependencies are located ? Should it even generate two .jar files (I believe the dependencies should already be in the server.jar).

Comment: The new jar contains your code and all the dependencies. So run that one: java -jar server-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Comment: You should explain what this does.  Also that this is most likely a duplicate.